# How to use global variables in WordPress using do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have

```
$a = 'blablablablabla';
function Test($atts, $content = null){
   global $a;
   return '<p>'.$a.'</p>';
}
add_shortcode('test', 'Test');
$x = do_shortcode($content);
remove_shortcode('test');

return $x;
```

But Test is not getting global variables of this place, I think it is because of the "do_shortcode", how can I get a global variable from outside the function?

Comment: Pass it as a function argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code this is working on my wordpress.

```
$GLOBALS['a'] = 'blablablablabla';
function Test($atts, $content = null){
   return '<p>'.$GLOBALS['a'].'</p>';
}
add_shortcode('test', 'Test');
```

> $content = '[test]';

```
$x = do_shortcode($content);
remove_shortcode('test');
echo $x;
exit;
```

The out put is

```
blablablablabla
```

Comment: You haven't changed anything, I am sure that do_shortcode is running, Test is being executed, I don't know why to you go nice and to me no.

Comment: @BlackCid i just say not give a content into do_shortcode. just pust your short code name like test. so do_shortcode is understand that run a Test function otherwise is not run any thing.

Comment: The problem is not the execution of the function Test, the problem is that in my wordpress, $a is empty inside the function, Test is not taking global values...

Comment: @BlackCid Please check your wordpress version is support shortcode or not http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I think you don't understand me, do_shortcode is running, Test is being executed, but inside Test, global variables are like new variables.

Comment: @BlackCid o i am sorry but i tested in wordpress8 that working. i put output also i am able to access global variable in do_shortcode.

Comment: @BlackCid Hey i edit my answer please check and try this is working or not.